# API that let's you edit/manipulate an image

Tags: javascript, image, edit

Is there an API that lets you add text to an image and fetch it to your app?

For example:
User uploads an image to my website.
User has the ability to add text (prices, locations, info) to the image through a third-party service and once ready I can make an API call to the service and fetch the new image to my server so the user can use the image for products or save it.

If there are no services like that how would I go about creating an image editor in JavaScript/jQuery so that user could add boxes/text to the image? I know that I would need to use ImageMagick to convert the data and render an image after the user has finished but image editing in the browser is an unexplored area for me.

Comment: Canvas can help you in-browser, but is this for just showing something to the user?  Must it actually be rendered?

Comment: Yes. The image will be displayed on a product type page and users can download the image, use it in a pdf file or send it through email.

Comment: I would use canvas then.  It's perfect for what you're trying to do, and then you don't have to worry about server-side rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can render and manipulate images in HTML/javascript:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/canvas-from-scratch-pixel-manipulation--net-20573

Comment: Vote up the answer if it helps, please :-)